# Entity Framework & StructureMap

Tags: c#, entity-framework, structuremap, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying a add-migration on my dal layer and getting the following error.

> Type 'StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException' in assembly 'StructureMap, Version=4.4.1.451, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

I use StructureMap within the DAL. Any help would be great.

Comment: You're going to need to show us some code to get an answer!

Comment: When you get an answer please post it here I'm getting the same error